# Getting individual values from PHP array

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
Array ( [sortorder] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [id] => Array ( [0] => 126 [1] => 127 ) )
```

I am wanting to get echo just the sortorder values, one per line. Tried several ways but can't work out how to get just the sort order values? I have started with...

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  foreach(id as $k)
  {
  echo '  <p>'.$k['id'].'</p>';
   }

}
```

Comment: What does your current code output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST['sortorder'] as $k => $v) {
  echo '<p>'.$k.': '.$v.'</p>';
}
```

---

edit:

if the array keys of both subarray are in the same order:

```
foreach ($_POST['sortorder'] as $k => $v) {
  echo '<p>'.$k.': '.$v.' - '.$_POST['id'][$k].'</p>';
}
```

not quite sure if that's what you want

Comment: If I wanted to echo each ID and the sortorder value together, would you have an idea how to do that?